# How to properly mock itnernal services in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I would like to learn how to properly mock object calls inside other classes, foor example I have this controller action:

```
def show
 service = Action::PartsShow.new(show_params, current_user)
 service.call
 render json: service.part, root: :part, serializer: PartSerializer, include: '**',
        scope: {current_user: current_user}
end
```

The service class looks like this.

```
module Action
  class PartsShow < PartsShowBase
    def find_part
      ...
    end
  end
end

module Action
  class PartsShowBase
    attr_reader :part

    def initialize(params, current_user)
      @params = params
      @current_user = current_user
    end

    def call
      find_part
      reload_part_availability
      reload_part_price if @current_user.present?
    end

    private

    def reload_part_availability
      ReloadPartAvailabilityWorker.perform_async(part.id)
    end

    def reload_part_price
      ExternalData::LauberApi::UpdatePrices.new(@current_user, [part]).execute
    end
  end
end
```

I don't want to call the actual `Action::PartsShow` service inside this controller action and all other methods, services + the worker because this makes the test very slow. What I want is to test if this service is being called and mock the rest of the services. I don't want to call them in my tests, I want to mock them.

My test looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe PartController, type: :request do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    let(:part) { create(:part) }

    subject { get "/api/v1/parts/#{part.id}" }

    expect(response_body).to eq(200)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Could you show me how to properly mock it? I've read about RSpec mocks and stubs but I am confused about it. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rspec-mocks gem, you can use `allow_any_instance_of`. Usually, this part lies in `before` block.

In fact,`Action::PartsShow` is responsible for loading a part, so there is no need to leak two instance methods: `call` and `part`. You can simplify it through returning the part from `call`.

```rb
module Action
  class PartsShowBase
    #attr_reader :part

    def call
      find_part # assign @part
      reload_part_availability
      reload_part_price if @current_user.present?
      @part
    end
    ...
end
```

```rb
RSpec.describe PartController, type: :request do
  before :all do
    allow_any_instance_of(Action::PartsShow).to receive(:call).and_return(returned_part)
  end
```

**Reference**

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will refactor this. This is a legacy code that I took over by another company. In fact, the code smells in my opinion and could be refactorred even further. Thanx!

Comment: What about the worker? Will it be called in the test? What about the ExternalData service? Will it be called as well?

Comment: If you stub the `Action::PartsShow#call`, its function body is skipped and just return what you specify in `and_return(...)`.

Comment: what about returning `success`? for example, there may be something like `if Import.perform(import: @import).success?`

Comment: `allow_any_instance_of` should be a _last resort_. There's even a rubocop rule about it: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rspec/cops_rspec.html#rspecanyinstance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `find_part` calls `Part.find(id)`, you can add:

```
before do
  allow(Part).to receive(:find).with(part.id).and_return(part)
end
```

to ensure that the record lookup always returns your test object. I also suggest reworking your spec a bit:

```
RSpec.describe PartController, type: :request do
  subject { response }
  
  describe '#show' do
    let(:request)  { get api_v1_part_path(part.id) }
    # If you insist on mocking the object, might as well use build_stubbed
    let(:part)     { build_stubbed(:part) } 
    let(:json)     { JSON.parse(response.body).deep_symbolize_keys }
    let(:expected) {
      {
        part: {
          id: parts.id,
          # ...
        }
      }
    }

    before do
      # This is the recommended way to mock an object
      allow(Part).to receive(:find).with(part.id).and_return(part)
      request
    end

    # Validate response status
    # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher
    # If you are using shoulda matchers - it works bc subject is the response
    it { should have_http_status(:success) }
    # otherwise
    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }

    # Validate response body
    it { expect(json).to eq(expected) }
  end
end
```

If your project has [path helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers), I would also recommend using those instead of the path string.

Comment: but you see, I don't want to even get there, I want to mock the entire `Action::PartsShow.new(show_params, current_user)` service to avoid calling it. I just want to expect that it is called and returns a value but I don't want to call it at all.

Comment: If you do that and the functionality of Action::PartsShow changes, your specs will not notify you that there is an issue with the core functionality of that controller. You can still do this with `allow(Action::PartsShow).to receive(:new).with(show_params, current_user) { service }` to ensure that any call with that method and those params (which you should define in your spec with let vars) will return that specific thing you’ve defined with a let var. It’s the same basic syntax and MUCH safer to use than allow_any_instance_of. `let(:service) { double(Action::PartShow, call: part) }`